# How to add TWO blank lines to comment in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-cards, markdown

What is the easiest way to add **two** blank lines to a comment on a card? If I do it manually, only one shows, and `<br>` doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent a blank line from being merged with surrounding blank lines by pasting a Unicode space character on the line you want to keep.  I tested this using U+202F (Narrow No-Break Space) copied from Character Map.  On Windows, it's possible to enter this from the keyboard using Alt codes, but it requires [changing a registry entry](https://superuser.com/a/47424).

Comment: This works like a charm, but it seems like you need to put a regular blank line _before_ the line containing this character for it to work in Trello.